# Templates and nested classes/structures

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, containers

I have a simple container :

```
template <class nodeType> list {
    public:
        struct node {
            nodeType info;
            node* next;
        };

    //...
};
```

Now, there is a function called `_search` which searches the list and returns a reference to the node which matched. Now, when I am referring to the return-type of the function, I think it should be `list<nodeType>::node*`. Is this right? When I define the function inline, it works perfectly:

```
template <class nodeType> list {
    public:
        struct node {
            nodeType info;
            node* next;
        };

        node* _search {
            node* temp;
            // search for the node
            return temp;
        }
};
```

But, if I define the function outside the class,

```
template <class nodeType> list<nodeType>::node* list<nodeType>::_search() {
    //function
}
```

it doesn't work. The compiler gives an error saying `Expected constructor before list<nodeType>::_search` or something. The error is something similar to this. I don't have a machine on which I can test it currently.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

that's because `node` is a dependent type. You need to write the signature as follows (note that I have broken it into 2 lines for clarity)

```
template <class nodeType> 
typename list<nodeType>::node* list<nodeType>::_search() 
{
    //function
}
```

Note the use of the `typename` keyword.

Comment: More, very geeky, details can be found in the C++ FAQ Lite: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18

Comment: Updated link for the FAQ: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#dependent-name-lookup-types

Answer (score 9):

You need to tell the compiler that `node` is a type using the keyword `typename`.Otherwise it will think node as a `static` variable in `class list`. Add `typename` whenever you use node as a type in your implementation of list.