# c++ templates and inner classes

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

Can someone please clarify inner class use with templates?  I have searched through books and internet examples to learn templates but few examples show inner class usage.  What I gathered so far is

```
template <class T>
class A
{
     class B
     {
         B()
         ~B()
     }

     A();
     ~A();

    B* a(T i, B* l);
}
```

From reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694063/templates-and-nested-classes-structures) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092237/c-nested-class-of-a-template-class) I believe I should define outer class constructor as

```
template <class T>
class A<T>::A()
{

}
```

but how am I defining the inner class constructor definition? How do I define the definition of a? I have struggled with this for most of the day trying to figure this out and really appreciate assistance.

Comment: `template <class T> A<T>::B::B() { ... }`

Comment: `template <class T> typename A<T>::B* A<T>::a(T i, B* l) { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `class` in the definition of the constructor of `A`, it should be

```
template <class T>
A<T>::A()
{
}
```

And for the constructor of `B`,

```
template <class T>
A<T>::B::B()
{
}
```

And for the member function `a`, use `typename` when refers to `A<T>::B`

```
template <class T>
typename A<T>::B* A<T>::a(T i, typename A<T>::B* l)
{
    return ...;
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/XCGS39555)