# Class Template with Nested Class Declaration (C++)

Tags: c++, class, templates, typename

Given that a class template called `Queue` with a nested class `Node` (not a class template):

```
template<typename T> 
class Queue {  

  private:

    struct Node {
        Node (T value) : value(value), next(nullptr) {}
        Node (T value, Node* next) : value(value), next(next) {}
        T value;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node* head;
    size_t sz;
    void cleanList();

  public:

    Queue();

    Queue(const Queue& st);
    Queue& operator=(const Queue& st);

    ~Queue();

    size_t size() const noexcept;
    bool isEmpty() const noexcept;

    T& front();
    const Tt& front() const;

    void enqueue(const T& elem);
    void dequeue(); 
};
```

I can do this:

```
template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(const T& elem) {

    Node* temp = new Node(elem);

}
```

It compiles, but why does declaring a `Node` not need more information? (like `Queue::Node`)

---

After reading [Templates and nested classes/structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694063/templates-and-nested-classes-structures), all 3 of these also works and compiles:

```
template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(const T& elem) {

    typename LLQueue<Object>::Node* temp1 = new Node(elem);
    LLQueue<Object>::Node* temp2;
    LLQueue::Node* temp3;

}
```

Why do all versions work? Which is preferred when using a nested class in a class template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It compiles, but why does declaring a `Node` not need more information?

This is how unqualified name lookup happens in a member function scope.  First the compiler checks the scope of the function, doesn't find anything, and then moves on to the class scope.  In the class scope it sees `Node`, so name lookup succeeds and you get the `Node` type that is a member of the class.

> Why do all versions work?

C++ lets you be as explicit as you want to be.  Any name can be fully qualified and that is what you are doing.  With `typename LLQueue<Object>::Node`, the `typename` isn't needed, but it doesn't hurt anything.  Its like doing `struct foo{}; struct foo f;` the `struct` isn't needed but it is allowed by the grammar. The second line with `LLQueue<Object>::Node` is just a less explicit way and also allowed since `typename` isn't actually required. `LLQueue::Node` works because in a class template `class_name` is injected into the class scope and it is `class_name<template_params>`.